# The Notepad++ tab bar keeps hiding

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to always force the tab bar to show?  I go to Settings → Preferences → General → Tab Bar and uncheck hide, but the next time I open Notepad++, the tab bar is gone, even if I drag multiple files into the window.

Comment: What version are you using? I'm using 5.9.6.2 and I haven't this issue.

Comment: I'm using the latest as of 2012-03-19... version 5.9.8

Comment: Turns out this happens when I place the file asNotepad.xml into the Notepad++ executable directory. I'd like to be able to show the tab bar in Notepad++ when dragging multiple files into a Notepad++ window. But I would also like to open a new Notepad++ instance when double-clicking a file from Explorer.

Comment: i have the same problem. whenever i started notepad++ with -notabbar, the next regular launch has the tabbar missing. ok, just found this: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4288/, known bug.

Comment: don't see the issue fixed even now (v6.6.9).

Answer (score 14):

Open notepad++ with `Run as Administirator` and uncheck `hide` again, and restart notepad++ . The problem should be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, other configurations can be saved but that one specific with tab bar is reset each time the program is started.